# Unbound DNS for lan network

Tags: networking, dns, lan, freebsd, unbound

I have problem with setting up dns server using unbound.

Unbound is set up on freeBSD ('dns.home.local' - 192.168.0.228) and it works, resolving local names (both 'gate' or 'gate.home.local') and forwarding everything else.

If I set up this 192.168.0.228 as dns server for other computer in this LAN (windows10 pro) it doesn't work as it should.

I mean, It works - it can resolve everything but my local zone.
I mean it sees "google.com" but it doesn't "gate.home.local" or "gate".

There is my unbound config.

```
server:
verbosity: 1
interface 0.0.0.0 #allow-all
do-ip4: yes
do-udp: yes
do-tcp: yes
access-control: 192.168.0.0/24 allow
hide-identity: yes
hide-version: yes
private-address: 192.168.0.0/24
private-domain: "home.local"
domain-insecure: "home.local"
unblock-lan-zones: yes
insecure-lan-zones: yes

local-zone: "home.local" static
local-data: "dns.home.local IN A 192.168.0.228"
local-data: "gate.home.local IN A 192.168.0.1"
local-data-ptr: "192.168.0.228 dns.home.local"
local-data-ptr: "192.168.0.1 gate.home.local"

forward-zone:
name: "."
forward-addr: 192.168.0.1
```

Yesterday I've tried to use BIND9 and I had the same problem - it was forwarding but doesn't resolv local zone.

I'm using freeBSD 11.2 on proxmox host.

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use the `.local` TLD instead of something else? It is reserved for mDNS and may have special treatment in resolvers.

Comment: I've just tried to change .local to .lan and it didn't change anything, but thanks for your note

Comment: `local-zone: "home.local" static` might just lack a trailing dot: `home.local.`